# How is a CRC32 checksum calculated with FreePascal(Lazarus)?

Tags: lazarus, crc32

I have to make some project for my college, and I need to calculate CRC32. But I almost didn't work with shifts before, so even after I read theory it's still hard to me. I found some CRC32 basic algorithm for C (not mine) and I tried to rewrite it for Lazarus(Delphi). But it doesn't work. I can't understand, what's wrong. Please, help (*_ _)人

Here my code:

```
procedure TMyFrame.CRC32_Checksum();
var
  P : Pointer;
  Size, i : Integer;
  CRC, j : LongWord;
  B : ^Byte;
  flag : Boolean;
begin
  AssignFile (f, FileName);
  Reset(f, 1);
  Size := FileSize(f);
  GetMem(P, Size);
  BlockRead(f, P^, Size);
  B := P;
  //
  //
  CRC := $FFFFFFFF;
  for i := 1 to Size do
    begin
      CRC := CRC XOR B^;
      Inc(B);
      for j := 0 to 7 do
        begin
          flag := (CRC AND 1) > 0;
          if flag then
            CRC := (CRC SHR 1) XOR $04C11DB7
          else
            CRC := CRC SHR 1;
        end;
      end;
  LabeledEdit1.Text := IntToHEX(CRC, 8);
  //
  //
  Freemem(P);
  CloseFile(f);
end;
```

Comment: We don't know what it is meant to do, and how it fails. You need to learn how to debug your program. That's your next task.

Comment: my program just looking for checksum and finds wrong numbers. It checks .txt file where "123456789" and it finds "0x340BC6D9", but it must be "0xCBF43926". I already tried to debug as you said, but I have no idea what's problem here. That's why I asking here about my problem

Comment: There are many variants of CRC32 algorithm. Who knows which one you want? Presumably you do. You have working C code, and now want Pascal code. Compare the execution of the two versions (Pascal against C). Find out where the two diverge. Fix, and repeat. When there is no more divergence, the task is done. Once again, your next task it to learn how to debug. This is the perfect opportunity. Would you like to learn how to debug? Or do you just want code that works?

Comment: I'd like to learn how to debug, I guess... okay then, I'll try once again

Comment: Just do what I say. Compare the execution of the two programs, the C version and the Pascal version. Output (e.g. to console) the value of `CRC` each time around the loop and compare the outputs of those two programs. Take it from there.

Comment: okay, I'll try do this(I absolutely forgot about that way for checking). Will see, what I get. Thanks

Comment: @Claire Your first comment here needs to be edited into the question. That is the actual information needed to provide any sort of help.

Answer (score 3):

`0xCBF43926` is the bit-wise inverse ("not") of `0x340BC6D9`. You just need to use `not` on the result, or exclusive or with `$FFFFFFFF`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that FPC comes with a CRC32 unit. (derived from crc32.c by Mark Adler, above )

This unit has a function to calculate the CRC for a block called crc32()

```
  function crc32 (crc : cardinal; buf : Pbyte; len : cardinal): cardinal;
```

The XOR is included in this crc32.crc32() function.